# print web page which contain code listing (with horizontal scrolling)

Tags: javascript, html, css, pretty-print, printing-web-page

In those months, I'm always reading at code listings on web page (manly brief and coincise tutorials) and these listings have scrollbar to allow horizontal navigation.
I would like to print to PDF those web pages but I would gain a cutted code.

I searched for a solution looking at html source code in search of quick configuration to modify, css solutions (overflow-x/y) and javascript scripts (jPrintArea and many homemade) but they are (as far as I have understood) all solution to be implemented by the Owner side and not the User side.

I wanted to know if someone know a script or a method to do that (or at least to print only the code listing block *with its original formatting*). I suppose it is a problem that the whole community met while learning how to develop with online tutorials.

I can't post images so here two examples:
http://codeincomplete.com/posts/2012/6/23/javascript_racer_v1_straight/
https://pgetov.wordpress.com/2013/05/25/first-person-shooter-scene-setup/

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable javascript temporary. I don't know if this works for you but it could be worth a try.

Source: [Mozillazine: Printing a scrollable frame](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=322061)

- You can always just copy paste the code to print it and reassamble the page manually.

Comment: I know I can copy-paste to Word but then I (usually) would loose the formatting of the whole webpage, with often terrific results. I would like to use it like last chance solution and look for a more effective method, if available. disabling javascript doesn't affect the scrollbar (the second link doesn't use javascript at all for its code listings).

Comment: you may want to add that to the question, because "...know a script or method to do that (or at least to print only the code listing)" implies you're searching for any method and not a method that keeps the formatting of the page.

Comment: added as suggested. It's the B plan print/copy only the code, the best would be have all webpage suitable for print to PDF.